# Is it possible to stop mysql errors for non-replicated databases breaking replication?

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I was a bit surprised to see a mysql slave show that replication had stopped due to a replication error. The error it showed was one from the master, but on a database that isn't replicated.

One the master there is the current config in `/etc/my.cnf` in the `[mysqld]` section:

```
binlog-do-db=some_db_1
binlog-do-db=some_db_2
binlog-do-db=some_db_3
```

On the slave these databases are replicated without issue. The replicated type we're using is `MIXED`. The error on the slave which stopped replication, however, was a statement relating to another database:

```
Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Table 'some_db_4.some_table' doesn't exist' on query.
```

I presume that this is because it was referenced with the `schema.table` syntax and not with a `use` statement, but is there a way of stopping this from happening? Am I right in saying that normally, if I ran the following:

```
USE some_db_2;
UPDATE some_table SET some_column = 1 WHERE some_column = 0;
USE some_db_4;
UPDATE some_table SET some_column = 2 WHERE some_column = 1;
```

Then only the first two lines would appear in the binlog? Whereas with:

```
UPDATE some_db_2.some_table SET some_column = 1 WHERE some_column = 0;
UPDATE some_db_2.some_table SET some_column = 2 WHERE some_column = 1;
```

both would appear in the binlog? Is it possible to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replication filtering works by filtering on whatever is the *default database* when you run the query -- not the database affected by the query.

So you can get into trouble if you use qualified table names, changing data in `some_db_4` while your current default database is not that database.

Similar problems exist if you do cross-database DML, like an INSERT into a table in some_db_3 from a SELECT from a table in some_db_4, which doesn't exist on the slave.

So the answer to your question is yes, you can avoid this error if you are careful to execute DML on the master *only* when your default database is the database affected by the statement.